# Calculated fields in elastic search index pattern

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I am parsing log files at regular intervals into my ELK system.
I am able to parse the files successfully and display the data in Kibana dashboard.

Currently, my data is of the following format
"total" : 7080
"approved" : 1001
"pending" : 6079

This data is successfully showing in Kibana dashboard. However, I want to show the values as percentages, like as follows
"total" : 7080
"approved-perct" : 14.14%
"pending-perct" : 86.86%

Is there any way to add two new fields, approved-perct, and pending-perct to my index pattern?

I am using logstash to parse my log files and send them to elastic search. In my logstash configuration I am using grok filters to get the data in my required format.
Kibana version : 7.3.1

I tried going over the following tutorials, but I cannot get any fruitful result
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.4/dynamic-templates.html
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-percentile-aggregation.html
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html

Answer (score 1):

I got exactly what I wanted in these links
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.3/search-request-body.html#request-body-search-script-fields

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BhmpDtS7g28